# Attach RTP (UDP streams) to browser using WebRTC instead of Applet

Tags: java, applet, webrtc, rtp, jmf

I have a web application that streams phone call RTP's to client machines.
This allows clients to listen to live phone calls from their browser.
Right now, I am doing it through a Java applet using JMF.

I was wondering if the RTP player part could be replaced with a WebRTC RTP player and attaching that RTP stream directly to a video/audio element.

I wish not to change any implementation from my application server. The main goal is to get rid of java applet and use an alternative RTP player without the use of any 3rd party application.

Any help / link / idea would be very appreciated.

Thank you!